# Webpack obfuscator not working with craco, maps disabled

Tags: reactjs, webpack, craco

today I have a very large problem using react & craco, I can't seem to get my webpack-obfuscator to do anything. I have disabled source maps, but to no avail.

This is my craco config:

```
const path = require("path");
const WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig) => {
      // Because CEF has issues with loading source maps properly atm,
      // lets use the best we can get in line with `eval-source-map`
      if (webpackConfig.mode === 'development' && process.env.IN_GAME_DEV) {
        webpackConfig.devtool = 'eval-source-map'
        webpackConfig.output.path = path.join(__dirname, 'build')
      }

      return webpackConfig
    },
    plugins: {
      add: [
        new WebpackObfuscator ({
          rotateStringArray: true
        }),
      ],
    },
  },

  devServer: (devServerConfig) => {
    if (process.env.IN_GAME_DEV) {
     // Used for in-game dev mode
     devServerConfig.writeToDisk = true
    }

    return devServerConfig
  }
}
```

I get no visible maps files when building, and I've put "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false" in my .env file that's located where the package.json is.

Hopefully someone has the answer as to why this is happening.

Kind regards, and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade a short config, you can use a construct that, if the condition is met, updates the configuration without using WebpackObfuscator:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      ...(process.env.IN_GAME_DEV && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && {devtool: 'eval-source-map'})
    }
  }
}
```

Also, if you need additional properties for the configuration, in addition to the dvttool, you can add them